# My browser is lagging after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: graphics

I have noticed that Chromium and other browsers have started to lag after I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried Google, but I did not find what I was looking for. I had no problems with this just a few days ago, before I upgraded to 18.04

Answer (score 0):

If they are not working properly like before, it maybe because you have less ram than you need! please install `htop` using this command:

`sudo apt install htop`

then open a terminal and type `htop`. now just open your browser and work with it. after you see lags on your system check the terminal you opened before. it will give you information about your resources and how much you are using of it.

if you are using HDD instead of SDD, and your `Swap` is configured, please check if it is used or not! it is good way to find out how much ram you need by default!!! (SDD hards mostly can work like RAM, but it cause highly usage on disk and your disk will be took damage faster than normal.

Comment: Not quite sure what exactly I am supposed to look after in htop

Comment: There is two column in the window, one is `Mem` and another one is `Swp`. please check them both. And please how much Ram you have on your system?

Comment: I have 13 GB to spare